# Vulkan API samples building fails

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, vulkan

I'm following this instruction: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/getting-started
And keep gettig the following error when compilling any module:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/sophour/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/sophour/Code/Android/VulkanAPIsamples/API-Samples/android/texel_buffer/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86 --target vulkan_sample}
[1/5] Building CXX object utils/CMakeFiles/vsamputils.dir/util.cpp.o
FAILED: /home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=i686-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot   -I/home/sophour/Code/Android/API-Samples/data -I/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/shaderc/third_party/glslang -I/home/sophour/Code/Android/VulkanAPIsamples/API-Samples/utils -I/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/native_app_glue -I/home/sophour/Code/Android/VulkanAPIsamples/API-Samples/utils/../android/vulkan_wrapper -I/home/sophour/Code/Android/VulkanAPIsamples/API-Samples/utils/../data -I/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/shaderc/include -isystem /home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -isystem /home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward -isystem /home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=24 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -std=c++11  -Werror -DVK_USE_PLATFORM_ANDROID_KHR -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT utils/CMakeFiles/vsamputils.dir/util.cpp.o -MF utils/CMakeFiles/vsamputils.dir/util.cpp.o.d -o utils/CMakeFiles/vsamputils.dir/util.cpp.o -c /home/sophour/Code/Android/VulkanAPIsamples/API-Samples/utils/util.cpp
In file included from /home/sophour/Code/Android/VulkanAPIsamples/API-Samples/utils/util.cpp:40:
In file included from /home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/shaderc/include/shaderc/shaderc.hpp:18:
In file included from /home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/memory:81:
/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/unique_ptr.h:76:2: error: delete called on 'shaderc::CompileOptions::IncluderInterface' that is abstract but has non-virtual destructor [-Werror,-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
        delete __ptr;
        ^
/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/unique_ptr.h:236:4: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::default_delete<shaderc::CompileOptions::IncluderInterface>::operator()' requested here
          get_deleter()(__ptr);
          ^
/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/shaderc/include/shaderc/shaderc.hpp:133:3: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::unique_ptr<shaderc::CompileOptions::IncluderInterface, std::default_delete<shaderc::CompileOptions::IncluderInterface> >::~unique_ptr' requested here
  CompileOptions() { options_ = shaderc_compile_options_initialize(); }
  ^
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I'm absolutely new to this and have no experience in native android development. Help me solve this, please-please! A need it badly for my thesis!

Ubuntu 14.04; 
Android Studio 3.1.2; 
NDK: r17; 
Compile SDK: API 24: Android 7.0 (Nougat); 
Gradle 3.3

Comment: First of all, get the latest sources from https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples

Comment: Done. (Initially I've imported samples directly from android studio and those samples were dated by Jule 2017 ). I've followed instructions on github, but no avail. Same error(

Comment: After I did `$ sudo apt-get install git cmake build-essential bison libx11-xcb-dev libxkbcommon-dev libmirclient-dev libwayland-dev libxrandr-dev` some missing packages were installed, but it didn't helped either. 
The issue seems to be in shaderc, but when I executed `$ ../../../ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk APP_STL:=gnustl_static APP_ABI=all NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=clang libshaderc_combined -j16` everything was ok

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is in the android NDK headers.  Specifically in:

Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/shaderc/include/shaderc/shaderc.hpp

They declare shaderc::CompileOptions::IncluderInterface as a virtual class, but have no virtual destructor:

```
  class IncluderInterface {
      public:
      // Handles shaderc_include_resolver_fn callbacks.
      virtual shaderc_include_result* GetInclude(const char* requested_source,
                                           shaderc_include_type type,
                                           const char* requesting_source,
                                           size_t include_depth) = 0;

      // Handles shaderc_include_result_release_fn callbacks.
      virtual void ReleaseInclude(shaderc_include_result* data) = 0;
  };
```

I would not normally recommend this, but it seems you have no other choice.  You could remove the -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor or -Werror from the make files so that it will not error out for that mistake?  Probably not a solution for the long term...  The better solution would be to find out who makes the third party header: shaderc.hpp and ask them nicely to fix it...

Other options would be to use OpenGL in the Java SDK, or to write the Vulkan part from scrap and not use the sample code.  I recently wrote an android app which uses Vulkan, and have not encountered this error.

Comment: By the way, the latest version of libshaderc has fixed this.  The new header can be viewed at: https://github.com/google/shaderc/blob/master/libshaderc/include/shaderc/shaderc.hpp

Comment: Thank you, @cerulean_quasar for your advice, but which make files do you mean? This? `/home/sophour/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake`? How can I remove `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor or -Werror` keys if it's android studio who's in charge? 

I also tried to git clone and build shaderc latest and I built it successfully after some tweaks with sources directories arrangement, but then gradle just never finishes building samples.

And substitution of the old shaderc.hpp with the new one haven't helped either)  They're identical in those parts which cause errors

Comment: I'm so confused... Later I'll try to make vulkan app from scratch, but if anyone comes up with other suggestions, please, share them

Comment: The following is a very good [Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/).  You don't need to use shaderc.

Comment: I cannot open this tutorial for some reason( But probably it's the same tutorial I've clonned with vulkan samples. I'm going to go for it